# what is the right jquery selector syntax to get all checkboxes with a certain class name?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selector

i have jquery code that loop through all checkboxes.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
```

I now need to make this code more restrictive because i now have other checkboxes on this page.  how can i change this so it only loops through all checkboxes with a certain class name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('input[type=checkbox].class').each(function () {`

Answer (score 1):

No need to include 'input' in the selector:

```
$(':checkbox.class')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox].myClassName').each(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just making a selection, does this really need to be in a loop?

This will return a jQuery object matching your criteria:

```
$('input.className[type=checkbox]')
```

if you need it in a loop:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('className')) {
         // Do Stuff Here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
 $('input:checkbox.class')
```