# Narrow jquery selection of checkboxes by a class name

Tags: jquery, filter, selector, selected, checked

I want to disable only checkboxes that are checked AND have a specific class.  There are a lot of very similar questions but I couldn't find anything that was able to get this working.

http://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/snfDM/

In the below example only the second item should be disabled:

```
  HTML:
  <input type="checkbox" class='boundParent' />
  <input type="checkbox" class='boundParent' checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="boundChild" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="boundChild" />

  Javascript:
  $('[input:checked][class*="boundParent"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: this is very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000592/what-is-the-right-jquery-selector-syntax-to-get-all-checkboxes-with-a-certain-cl?rq=1 but I need to filter what is actually checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input.boundParent:checked").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('input[type="checkbox"][class*="boundParent"]:checked').prop("disabled", true);
```

OR

```
$(':checkbox:checked[class="boundParent"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

OR

```
$(':checkbox:checked.boundParent').prop("disabled", true);
```

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/snfDM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox:checked[class*="boundParent"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked").hasClass("boundChild").prop("disableb",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.runTest').click(function(){
    $('input[class^="bound"]:checked').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

​
You can check this here
http://jsfiddle.net/9D8Xw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RCjgQ/)

```
$('.boundParent:checked').prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

most succinct form i can think of would be

```
$('input.boundParent[type=checkbox]:checked').prop("disabled", true);
```

I have a few comments on other answers

```
// will select radioboxes as well 

$("input.boundParent:checked").prop("disabled", true);


// :checkbox is deprecated now

$(':checkbox:checked[class*="boundParent"]').prop("disabled", true);
```